# Screen Mirroring of Samsung Flip WMR55 to Windows 11

Tags: screencasts, smart-tv, whiteboard

I have in my office a Samsung Flip WMR55 which supports Screen Mirroring to show its screen content to another device. What I want to achieve is that I can stream the screen to my Windows 11 laptop to restream it over MS Teams.

Is there any programm besides Microsoft's own "project to PC" feature because I could not find my laptop on the Flip it and counter-checked with another device to make sure the firewall is the culprit. The Flip is connected by LAN and the other devices are connected to the same network by Ethernet or corporate WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

You may Miracast to a PC, but only if the right hardware is present.

To setup Miracast on Windows do this :

- Run *Setting > Apps > Optional features*
- Search for `Wireless display` and click on it to install
- Go to *Settings > System > Projecting to this PC*.
  If you see the message
  "This device doesn't support receiving Miracast, so you can’t
  project to it wirelessly", then your PC is not capable of receiving
  Miracast.
- If all goes well, select suitable options for casting to this PC.

Commercial third-party products exist, if Miracast is not
supported, and you may search the internet for them.